# Package Errors. What Am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, package, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a package that works out the number of days between two dates, I'm aware I have probably got this miles wrong, I am really struggling to troubleshoot this. My knownledge is low on oracle, I'm still quite new to this. The package I've written is below, but I am getting the error shown at the bottom.

How do I resolve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKNAME
   AS
   FUNCTION TIME_SCALE RETURN NUMBER;
   END;
/
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKNAME
   AS   closed_date := '28-APR-14'
   FUNCTION TIME_SCALE RETURN NUMBER;
   IS BEGIN
   TRUNC(mrc.closed_date - mrc.open_date) AS days_difference FROM     TASKS mrc;
   END;
```

​

```
Error at line 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the     following: constant exception <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table     long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar
```

I have substituted some of the names to make them clearer for you to read.

The function is to output the number of days it has taken for a task to be completed. The columns basically include the date_opened and date_closed in simple terms as well as a few others and a unique ID which I believe is a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKNAME
AS
  FUNCTION TIME_SCALE
    RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKNAME
AS
  closed_date VARCHAR2(50):= '28-APR-14';
  days_difference NUMBER;
FUNCTION TIME_SCALE
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT TRUNC(mrc.closed_date - mrc.open_date) INTO days_difference
  FROM TASKS mrc;
  RETURN days_difference;
END;
END;
```

What was wrong:

1) You have missed the type for closed_date 
2) You had an ';' after RETURN NUMBER in function declaration
3) You have missed SELECT clause inside function
4) You have missed END for the package

Comment: Throwing up an error at line 3: Error at line 3: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: The function isn't returning anything; don't you want `days_difference` declared inside the function, and that value returned? (And another item for your 'what was wrong list!)

Comment: Well, syntactically the function can return nothing. The question was not about the logic of the function, but rather why the package does not get created.

Comment: It'll compile, sure, but you'll get ORA-06503 when you call it. Fair enough though; just pre-empting the next question *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Okay then, on your discussion, how do I make one that will call? you've confused me now.....

Comment: @Chuck - @Guneli has added the `return` to the function now; so you'll get an answer if you `select packname.time_scale from dual;`. I wasn't trying to add confusion <sigh>

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks, I know you weren't trying to add confusion, you've actually put me in a better place as I had not noticed :)

Comment: @AlexPoole ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows upon trying to call.

Comment: Dear @Chuck, it is all about your table structure and input data now. You get this error cause the SELECT inside function returns more than one row. I do not think it is an expected behaviour for the function with NUMBER return type.

Comment: I understand this, but is there a solution to amend this error?

Comment: Of course, there is a solution. Can you, please, edit your question and describe the expected behaviour of your function?

Comment: @Chuck - you want the difference for a particular task, but you have no `where` clause so it's trying to get the difference for every row in the table - hence the error. You need to pass the ID you're interested in as parameter to the function, and then use that in the `where` clause so it only calculates the value for that specific row. (Of course, this is the kind of divergence from the original question that Guneli was trying to avoid 12 comments ago... sorry)